# How to show Bx-slider on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I want to show bx-slider on click of button. I need to show three slider in a row with three button. When someone click on any button one slider activate and other are hidden. But when I used to click on button it does not showing the images only the slider opens and arrows are visible. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
        <style>
            .slider{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

                $('.open').click(function(){
                $('.slider').show();
                $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="open">Open Slider</a>
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="bxslider">
                <li><img src="http://landscapelook.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/beauty_of_nature_images_gallery.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://stuffpoint.com/nature/image/277236-nature-nature-beauty-scenery-bridge.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img src="http://www.images-gededah.in/wp-content/uploads/Beauty-of-Nature20.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

link for the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h8teec45/

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the CSS line where you hide the slider and hide your slider with jQuery using this(see `$('.slider').hide();`):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  $('.slider').hide();
  $('.open').click(function(){
   $('.slider').show();
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  });
  
});
```

And it should work just fine.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8teec45/1/).